# scroll to element on reload page react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to scroll to the element after page reloads. I'm trying to `ref` the element and scroll to it after page reloads.

My current example will just scroll to the end of the page

```
const transactionRef = useRef(null)
const scrollToElemet = () => {
    transactionRef.current.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' });
  }

  useEffect(scrollToElemet)

return (
  <div ref={transactionRef}></div>
)
```

How can I calculate the position of the element and scroll to it on page reload? Thanks

Comment: with animation scrolling or simple move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this answer because querying the DOM in react is an anti-pattern:

```
export default function App() {
  const footerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    footerRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="main">Main</div>
      <div ref={footerRef} className="footer">
        Footer
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-60229673-FooterRef]

Comment: yup, I just realized what have I done, also I need to use `forwardRef` so it's a totally different story.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, add an element at the bottom of your page and then use that element to scroll. Here is a sample

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dhawan-k7q8b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Also, you need to pass `[]` as second argument so it only scroll on first mount otherwise it will keep on scrolling down to bottom on every change or on every render.

```js
function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("footer").scrollIntoView();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <span onClick={() => setChecked(v => !v)}>{checked ? "Enable" : "Disable"}</span>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className="main">Main</div>
      <div id="footer" className="footer">
        Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```